# Use an unmanaged DLL in Apache Cordova project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Is it possible to use an unmanaged DLL (C++) in an Apache Cordova project? How?

I tried to follow the instructions on this [page](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_win8_plugin.md.html) but I didn't understand where do I reference the DLL and its methods.

---

UPDATE

It seems to be possible creating a Windows Runtime Component that references the unmanaged DLL and Cordova plugin pointing to the winmd file, however it seems that the method call is not working. I don't receive any error message and can't even debug as Visual Studio still does not have debugging capability for Apache Cordova projects.

Comment: I have not done so, but you might want to reference "Create a Cordova plugin for Windows and Windows Phone" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903769.aspx

Comment: I have created a windows runtime component referencing the unmanaged dll and created a plugin referencing this winmd component, but the method is not being called (visual studio still can't debug this kind of project).

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope. The project has been cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

The next version of the Cordova Command Line Interface will improve support for multiple chip architectures when using a C++ based Windows Runtime component in a Cordova plugin.

You can see details here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/164

We are also working to ensure that the Visual Studio debugger is able to attach to Windows Phone (which is what I assume you are referring to above) when using the Windows Phone (Universal) platform target for Phone 8.1.  Windows 8.0/8.1 debugging is already supported.  In the mean time, you can open up the solution in the bld/Debug/platforms/windows after building for Windows as a tactical workaround. Stay tuned for an update in the coming weeks.